# Is there a way to reverse the order of a macro?

Tags: c, macros

Hello (I apologise in advance if I'm wrong in the tittle),

I'm writing a program and all, I created a macro but I want to use it in a reverse order like:

```
#define MAGIC "\x34\x19\x23\x4C"
```

Would become something like :

```
"\x4C\x23\x19\x34"
```

Is there a way to do it or I need to write a new one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What macro? Why a macro? What do you mean by "use" exactly?

Comment: I don't see any macros here. `"\x34\x19\x23\x4C"` is a string literal

Comment: `"\x34\x19\x23\x4C"`this is not a macro. It should start with `#defibe`

Comment: Macros don't use any memory unless you actually use them. What would be the purpose of using a macro in reverse order instead of writing a new one?

Comment: It's just to avoid using new lines but apparently it's better to do it..

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe you shouldn't use a macro at all for this.

Comment: Remember that a string literal is a char array. You can define a new char array like `char[5]{MAGIC[3],MAGIC[2],MAGIC[1],MAGIC[0],0}`. But this is no longer a string literal and as such is temporary,  so it depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor is responsible for macros (so they are interpreted before your program executes).

If you would like to use both `"\x34\x19\x23\x4C"` and `"\x4C\x23\x19\x34"` in your code it would be much better to declare a static global variable and then modify it by simple reverse function. Or, in fact, declare two macros.